# asp.net mvc2: Why to minimize the code in controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I heard a bit about we should keep the code in controllers as less as possible. So where do we put those code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will depend on what code you are talking about. For example if you are talking about validation, this should go into the model, if you are talking about data access this should also go into a repository or the model (personally I prefer repository), if you are talking about a business logic this should go into a service, so that all that's left into the controller is to call this thing and pass the result to the view.

I would recommend you watching [this video presentation](http://www.viddler.com/explore/mvcconf/videos/1/) about how to put your controllers on a diet from Jimmy Bogard.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know thin and skinny controller? So my answer is if you put many line of codes in controller, your code will be messy and hard to unit testing. Really the controller only executing the actions related with current HttpContext, so if you have business logic, data access, encryption,... you must separation of concern. The reason you don't put business logic at here is business belong to domain. So delegate to Domain for processing. Controller must be consider all actions related to HttpContext (Session, ViewData, TempData, User in current thread, Global and Local Resources,... ) and delegated all other actions to other component. Rule of thumb is fat model and thin controller for cook delicious cake(phpcake).
Some links you can reference for skinny and fat Controller at [here](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/asp-net-mvc-controller-best-practices-%E2%80%93-skinny-controllers/) and here.

Comment: See http://www.mikebernat.com/blog/MVC_-_Fat_Models_and_Skinny_Controllers_ for more information about my answer!